How to configure Debian Exim to deliver through a relay only if a remote server rejects with certain messages (e.g., "<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>_is_blocked.")
Using exim4 on Debian, how do I configure exim to attempt redelivery if I get a reject like:
553 5.3.0 alph747 DNSBL:RBL 521<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>_is_blocked ...
So, periodically my email server makes it onto a spamhaus list that spamhaus says "don't use this list to blacklist" but everyone does.  So I take my server off every year or two.  But now AT&T seems to be doing it.  So I can buy a relay service which makes me pay per message, but I only want to use it if necessary.  We only send a few dozen emails a day.
Just to be clear, my ip isn't on spamhaus or any spam list on DNSBL or mxtoolbox.  ATT just says so.
